# Error 500 jsp Ayuda

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

```html
votar en contra
accept
 <label required>Departamentos</label>
  <select class="form-control" onchange="buscarProvincia(this);" id="nIdeDptoNac">                  
           <option value="${cmb.nIdeCompendio}">--Seleccione--</option>                            
           <c:forEach var="cmb" items="${combo}">
           <option value="${cmb.nIdeCompendio}">${cmb.vNomCorto}</option>
           </c:forEach>
                            
 </select>
```

estoy tratando de llenar un combobox(select) en un jsp con servlet y jstl pero me manda error a una linea de codigo , la reviso y todo esta bien, haber si me pueden ayudar!!!... les dejo lo que tengo hasta ahora
El error me manda en la linea 34 del servlet (null pointer)
el select de mysql me duelve datos

```
public class ComboDAOimpl {
Connection conn = null;
PreparedStatement pstm = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
CatDetCompendioDTO catDetCompendioDTO =null;

public List<CatDetCompendioDTO> llenarCombos(String sql){
    List<CatDetCompendioDTO> listaCombo = new ArrayList<CatDetCompendioDTO>();
    try {
        conn = Conexion.getConexion();
        pstm = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = pstm.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            catDetCompendioDTO = new CatDetCompendioDTO();
            catDetCompendioDTO.setnIdeDetalle(rs.getInt("nIdeDetalle"));
            catDetCompendioDTO.setvNomCorto(rs.getString("vNomCorto"));
            catDetCompendioDTO.setvNomLargo(rs.getString("vNomLargo"));
            listaCombo.add(catDetCompendioDTO);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return listaCombo;
}

----------------------------------------------------------
```

@WebServlet("/comboController")
public class comboController extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

```
public comboController() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
ComboService comboService;

protected void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    req.setAttribute("combo", comboService.listarDepartamentosService());
    req.getRequestDispatcher("listaPeliculas.jsp").forward(req, res);
}
```

public class ComboServiceImpl implements ComboService {

```
 private ComboDAO comboDepartamento;

public List<CatDetCompendioDTO> listarDepartamentosService() {

    List<CatDetCompendioDTO> listaDepartamento = new ArrayList<CatDetCompendioDTO>();
    StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();
    sql.append("select nIdeDetalle,vNomCorto,vNomLargo from catdetcompendio where nidecompendio=9  order by vNomCorto");
    try {
        listaDepartamento   = comboDepartamento.llenarCombos(sql.toString());
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return listaDepartamento;
}
```

---

`

Comment: Por favor, pon el código como texto en la pregunta, puedes [editar] cuando quieras. Las imágenes no se ven siempre bien y no se puede copiar-pegar en una respuesta o para hacer pruebas

Comment: Tienes parte del código como texto normal y no se entiende bien. Edítalo por favor.

Comment: Dices que el error se produce en la línea 34... ¿esa cual es?

Comment: es en el comboController
 req.setAttribute("combo", comboService.listarDepartamentosService());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el controller te estás limitando a declarar un atributo de tipo ComboService pero no lo estás instanciando en ningún lado ni estás delegando en algún framework adicional para que te lo inyecte, motivo por el cual se produce ese NullPointer del que hablas.

Si realmente lo estás inyectando o inicializando en otro lado, adjunta ese código. En caso contrario, la solución es tan simple como:

```
ComboService comboService = new ComboServiceImpl();
```

Aunque viendo el código, probablemente luego te pasará lo mismo pero con el atributo comboDepartamento que tienes en el servicio.

Comment: la estoy inicializando como variable global  en la segunda imagen del controler donde dice  

ComboService comboService;

Comment: A esa línea me refiero. Ahí no la estás inicializando, sólo la estás declarando. Tras esa línea, comboService no tiene valor asignado de ningún tipo